# Where is my logical error in this python script for capitalizing first letters of a sentence when there are multiple sentences?

Tags: python

I have a logical error I can't find. I am trying to capitalize the first letter of each sentence. I am having trouble understanding how to move on to the next sentence to capitalize the first letter. How do I move to the next sentence? If you see my error can you please tell me what it is?

```
def main():

# get a string from the user
   stringAsked = input('Please enter a short statement consisting of a couple or more sentences ')

# call the capitalize function
   modifiedString = capitalize(stringAsked)

# Print the string
   print(modifiedString)


def capitalize(my_string):
    # Initialize string and counter variables
    modString = ''
    ind = 0

    # Create while loop to cycle through each character of the string
    while ind < len(my_string):

        # Assign Current character to the ch variable
        ch = my_string[ind]

        # If first character of string
        if ind == 0:

            # Store capitalized character in return variable
            modString += ch.upper()

        # Check if the character is at the end of the string
        elif ch == '.' or ch == '!' or ch == '?':

            # add current character to the return variable
            modString += ch

            # If more than one sentence
        if ind + 2 < len(my_string):

        # Add the space
            modString += my_string[ind + 1]

            # Capitalize the first character
            modString += my_string[ind + 2].upper()

            # Increment the index
            ind = ind + 2

        # If the character is in the middle of a sentence
        else:

            #Add the character to return variable
            modString += ch

        #increment the index to go to next character
        ind = ind + 1

    # return the variable to calling function
    return modString

main()
```

Comment: You could use a regular expression to split the string into sentences, rather than doing this character by character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation of your code regarding what to do after "." may seem to be the issue. You need the handling of the space and character after a full stop (or similar) to be indented so it is executed inside the "." condition and not as another condition at the same level.

```
def main():

# get a string from the user
   stringAsked = input('Please enter a short statement consisting of a couple or more sentences ')

# call the capitalize function
   modifiedString = capitalize(stringAsked)

# Print the string
   print(modifiedString)


def capitalize(my_string):
    # Initialize string and counter variables
    modString = ''
    ind = 0

    # Create while loop to cycle through each character of the string
    while ind < len(my_string):

        # Assign Current character to the ch variable
        ch = my_string[ind]

        # If first character of string
        if ind == 0:

            # Store capitalized character in return variable
            modString += ch.upper()

        # Check if the character is at the end of the string
        elif ch == '.' or ch == '!' or ch == '?':

            # add current character to the return variable
            modString += ch

            # If more than one sentence
            if ind + 2 < len(my_string):

                # Add the space
                modString += my_string[ind + 1]

                # Capitalize the first character
                modString += my_string[ind + 2].upper()

                # Increment the index
                ind = ind + 2

        # If the character is in the middle of a sentence
        else:

            #Add the character to return variable
            modString += ch

        #increment the index to go to next character
        ind = ind + 1

    # return the variable to calling function
    return modString

main()
```

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Checking `if ind + 2 < len(my_string):` only needs to occur after a "." has been detected. In your code, you are checking `index == 0` and then `elif ch == '.' or ch == '!' or ch == '?':` AND THEN you are checking `if ind + 2 < len(my_string):`. You need to do this check if `elif ch == '.' or ch == '!' or ch == '?':` is true, therefore the code needs to be inside this if statememt

Answer (score -1):

What about this - first split the string at every "." and then walk through every sentence and switch first letter to capital.

```
s = "hello world. please help me. can we do this simpler?"
stringlist = s.split(". ")

def first_char_upper(stringlist):
  for i in range(0, len(stringlist)):
    stringlist[i] = stringlist[i][0].upper() + stringlist[i][1:]
  return stringlist

print(first_char_upper(stringlist))
```

Output: `> ['Hello world', 'Please help me', 'Can we do this simpler?']`